# Windows Server 2012 has incorrect decimal digits for currency on es-CL culture

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server

Windows Server 2012 seems to have several issues regarding CultureInfo. The information about decimal digits for currencies in culture es-CL (that's Chile) is incorrect, it says 2 digits but here in Chile we don't use decimals in our currency.

Do anyone knows about a patch or maybe a way to override this setting? Modifying the Windows Locale options does not work for me, because I need this working on a MVC 5 site.

Any help, will be greatly appreciated.

PS: I never had this trouble with my dev-machine (I've use from Win7 to 10), so I'm guessing this issue only exists on Windows Server 2012

Comment: Just a thought, can you pick another culture that works for you, or how about this; stay with this one an let the application layer mask the digits properly?

Comment: Is it definitely picking up the rest of the locale correctly?

Comment: I'm not an expert but en-US and es-ES work fine. I can't use other culture, since the final user of the MVC 5 site is the one who configures this.

Comment: BTW I can always just overwrite the CultureInfo object in C#, though I don't like that Idea since it's an OS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel check this configuration and try it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0A4d.png

Comment: I've tried that, it only works for windows environment. Since IIS uses raw settings for websites, this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me tell you this is not what I need, but I will leave it here in case someone else needs a patch for this.

One alternative is to "patch" the source code in order to override the amount of decimal digits used in currencies (you can override all properties you want). To do this you have to Create a Specific Culture using as base the one you want to override:

```
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-CL");
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
```

And then assign this "culture" variable to the "Current Thread":

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Finally, if you are using MVC as me, you can add this code into an "ActionFilterAttribute" in order to make all calls use this settings:

```
public class LocalizationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-CL");
        culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    }
}
```

And don't forget to register your Filter, in your Global.asax include the following line:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new LocalizationFilter());
```