# Persian culture in Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: c#, globalization, windows-server, persian-calendar

In our development machine which is running on Windows 10, "fa-IR" culture works fine and all dates display using Persian calendar. But when we deploy our app on Windows Server 2012 r2, datetime is still in Gregorian.

Comment: What do you mean "fa-IR culture works fine"? How are you using it in your application? Or is it an OS setting?

Comment: i user like this DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa-IR")). In windows 10 date time display as Persian but in server is Gregorian.

Comment: Locale settings on both the machines are same?

Comment: yes. but there is a difference between them.
in the "Current system location" of windows 10 "Persian (Iran)" is available but in server "Persian"  is available.
I don't know if it can affect or not.

Answer (score 2):

for clarification of the problem we have with fa-IR in Windows Server2012, here is an example that works fine in Windows 10 but do not work in Windows 2012:

```
DateTime startDate;
CultureInfo c = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fa-IR");
DateTime.TryParse("1990/02/01", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate);
Console.WriteLine(startDate.ToString("D", c));
```

The Windows 10   result (fine):    پنجشنبه, 12 بهمن 1368 
The Windows 2012 result (just persian letters):پنجشنبه، 01 فوريه 1990

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that the `fr-IR` culture is not installed on the server.

See [Installing more cultures on Windows Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281161/installing-more-cultures-on-windows-server-2012) for more help.

Comment: Thank you.
when i use this sample c# code and i want to LoadDataFromCultureInfo from "fa-IR" culture i have an error with this error message "Custom calendars are not currently supported"

Comment: Maybe this will help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2013/11/18/locale-builder-v2-0-for-windows-8-1server-2012-r2-released/

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the version of Windows,  Persian calendar was added in Windows Server 2012 R2 And Windows 10.

[SQL Server FORMAT with culture parameter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60135189/1442180)

Comment: In Windows 2012 R2 when we use "fa-IR" date-time will be translated to Persian, like "پنجشنبه، 01 فوريه 1990".
finally, we just upgrade windows version to 2016 and problem fixed.